# Opera not loading Java applet

Tags: java, internet, browser, plugin, opera

Opera fails using Java. The [online test](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) is negative.

```
~ $ locate libnpjp2.so
/home/USER/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

The tutorial on [Opera's webpage](http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/#java) is outdated. It refers to a non-existing directory, where Opera browser should be installed:

```
~ $ cd /usr/lib/opera/plugins
bash: cd: /usr/lib/opera/plugins: No such file or directory
```

According to Opera's manual, the only problem might be the missing link to the existing java installation directory. But where is the folder ../plugins ? I cannot find it in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/opera/

My PC runs with Linux Mint 18 Xfce 32-bit

Comment: I found out, that with Firefox the Java plugin test is also negative: "Starting with Firefox Version 52 (released in March 2017), Firefox has limited support for plug-ins, and therefore will not run Java. Use the Java Control Panel to find the installed Java version." –  via Firefox about:plugins now I know that only Firefox Extended Support Release will load Java applets, so I installed Firefox ESR - [like that](http://askubuntu.com/a/897911/520965)

Comment: if you want to have the newest Java version - "justched" seems to be the easiest solution - [check it out here](http://askubuntu.com/a/753555/520965)

Comment: @ gloschtla I have followed those 3 commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install firefox-esr` and I receive the following: `The following packages have unmet dependencies.` firefox-esr : Depends: libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not going to be installed` `opera-stable : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.5 is to be installed` `Recommends: pepperflashplugin-nonfree but it is not going to be installed` `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` Did you find these problems?